# Can't use texture paint in the skirt moddel?

Tags: texture-painting

What it says on the tin. I can't paint on anything, let alone what I actually want to paint on (the skirt). Feel free to look at the file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rX-h4S48ZmKqzv6MU376UTy1xCIkxsU/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're painting using a black texture. Remove it using the 'x' cross button.

[image]

Comment: omg you legend, thank you lol